# Not implemented Error for reports with Charts (Graphs) on Azure

Tags: azure, crystal-reports, charts

I installed Crystal Reports on Windows Azure, and most reports work just fine.  However, none of the reports with charts work.  I get Operation not yet implemented error from my web page.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a url to such a non working report? Which operation does it state is not implemented?

Comment: I cannot really publish the URL.  It just says Operation Not Implemented, not additional info provided.  I know now it is "not suported" on Azure, which makes no sense to me.  http://scn.sap.com/thread/3236182

Answer (score 0):

If you can install all the needed SAP, I understood that from [the thread you mentioned](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3236182), on a server on premises you could try one of the following options:

- Start up a webrole, rdp into it and install what's needed
- Create a startup task that installs the needed material. [See this for example](http://danieljsinclair.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/how-i-got-net-4-5-rc-running-in-a-windows-azure-webrole/).
- Make use of the new IaaS capabilities in Azure. Create a new server from one of the images in the gallery or upload a [sys prepped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465407.aspx) image with the stuff you need on it to Azure.

Comment: I have everything working in a web role, except charts.  SAP is using a third party charting, and that is what does not work.  I was trying really hard to avoid a VM role (IaaS) as it take more effort.

Comment: An alternative would be SQL Server Reporting Services which also works on Azure.